# XSLT templates: change the order of processing nodes from source

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I am learning XSLT and how to use templates.

I have the following (simplified) input:

```
<root>
    <parent1 num="123" />
    <parent2 type="ABC">
        <child1>702</child1>
    </parent2>    
</root>
```

I would like to use a template to transform this to:

```
<item>
    <childentry>702</childentry>
    <parententry>ABC</parententry>
</item>
```

with the help of a template.

And more as a general question: how can you change the order of processing nodes from source by using templates.

Suggestions are really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using XSLT 1.0, there is an explanation in the XSLT 1.0 specification here:

https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#section-Applying-Template-Rules

See the paragraph starting "Multiple xsl:apply-templates elements can be used within a single template to do simple reordering."

Some general tips:

- Are you really constrained to use XSLT 1.0? Later versions (2.0 and 3.0) are much more powerful and make some common operations much easier.
- Is StackOverflow the right place for this kind of question? What resources are you using for learning the language? There are plenty of good books available and they surely cover this.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. I found the explanation, but am however struggling to find the corresponding input file that would help me get the output and see the exact effect. It seems though this reorders nodes that are at the same level: sales/domestic vs sales/foreign. I am wondering how to get an element "above" other element in a source XML and "shift" it "below" in the output.

Comment: Some general comments:
1) I am currently constrained to XSLT 1.0 as I am working with Javascript and cannot find processors for 2.0 and 3.0
2) I totally believe StackOverflow is the right place for this kind of question. Have covered several tutorials and practiced XSLT transformations myself, yet I cannot deal with this one.

Comment: Saxon-JS gives you XSLT 3.0 in the browser if you need it. If you have questions like this in future, it's easier to answer the question if we know how far you have got with your researches so far.

Comment: "I am wondering how to...". Think in terms of structuring the stylesheet according to the output, not the input. "The next thing I want to output is X; this is where I need to go to find the necessary information in the input". If you think in terms of the input ("This is the next thing in the input, what should I do with it?") then you'll get stuck.